# Frameset on multiple pages

Tags: html, frame

I want to make `frameset` with multiple frames, but I want each frame to have a specific size regardless of how many columns. I want this `frameset` to expand to multiple pages if needed with a scroll bar ( scroll bar not for the individual frame but for the whole html page) . What I noticed is that all these frames are forced to fit on one `html` window and so the frames forcibly get resized to fit in one page .

Is there any way to respect the size I indicate , and the `html` page occupy multiple pages with a scroll bar so I don't compromise the size of each frame?

Example :

```
<html>

<frameset cols="1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_b.htm">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_c.htm">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_b.htm">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_c.htm">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_b.htm">
  <frame noresize="noresize" src="frame_c.htm">
</frameset>

</html>
```

these individual frames get resized to fit the `html` window and are not 1000 each.